# How to get the intersect of a dictionary from two files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the intersect of dictionaries across 2 files, but coming up empty.
The test files look like this.

**`jwks1`:**

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "5Of9P5F9gCCwCmF2BOHHxDDQ-Dk",
      "x5t": "5Of9P5F9gCCwCmF2BOHHxDDQ-Dk",
      "n": "2y6laZ",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "x5c": [
        "MIIDB"
      ]
    },
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEg",
      "x5t": "nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEg",
      "n": "oaLLT",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "x5c": [
        "44Dw7"
      ]
    },
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "18pnMg3UmrWvBK_tkDAbjgM5CmA",
      "x5t": "18pnMg3UmrWvBK_tkDAbjgM5CmA",
      "n": "v3tn9",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "x5c": [
        "3dQ=="
      ]
    },
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "DqUu8gf-nAgcyjP3-SuplNAXAnc",
      "x5t": "DqUu8gf-nAgcyjP3-SuplNAXAnc",
      "n": "1n7-nWS",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "x5c": [
        "9pIcnkPQ=="
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**`jwks2`:**

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEg",
      "x5t": "nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEg",
      "n": "oaLLT",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "x5c": [
        "44Dw7"
      ]
    },
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "l3sQ-50cCH4xBVZLHTGwnSR7680",
      "x5t": "l3sQ-50cCH4xBVZLHTGwnSR7680",
      "n": "sfsXMXW",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "x5c": [
        "QGBWrh+/vJ"
      ]
    },
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "DqUu8gf-nAgcyjP3-SuplNAXAnc",
      "x5t": "DqUu8gf-nAgcyjP3-SuplNAXAnc",
      "n": "1n7-nW",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "x5c": [
        "Lu9pIcnkPQ=="
      ]
    },
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "OzZ5Dbmcso9Qzt2ModGmihg30Bo",
      "x5t": "OzZ5Dbmcso9Qzt2ModGmihg30Bo",
      "n": "01re9a",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "x5c": [
        "J6sDdRvQ=="
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my code thus far:

```
import json

def getjwk1():
    with open('jwks1', 'r') as az:
        json_1 = json.load(az)
        return json_1

def getjwk2():
    with open('jwks2', 'r') as az:
        json_2 = json.load(az)
        return json_2

json1_dict = getjwk1()
json2_dict = getjwk2()
common_pairs = dict()
for key in json1_dict:
    if (key in json2_dict and json1_dict[key] == json2_dict[key]):
        common_pairs[key] = json1_dict[key]
print(common_pairs)
```

Result:

```
{}
```

Expecting:

```
  {"kty": "RSA",
  "use": "sig",
  "kid": "nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEg",
  "x5t": "nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEg",
  "n": "oaLLT",
  "e": "AQAB",
  "x5c": [
    "44Dw7"
  ]}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better, more optimal way to do this?

Comment: 1. Each dictionary has only one key: `'keys'` - and their values differ. That is why there is no intersection. 2. Why do you need two functions that do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the list of dictionaries in the `'keys'` value:

```py
import json 

with open('jwks1') as az:
    json1_dict = json.load(az)

with open('jwks2') as az:
    json2_dict = json.load(az)

common_pairs = []
for d in json1_dict['keys']:
    if d in json2_dict['keys']:
        common_pairs.append(d)
print(json.dumps(common_pairs,indent=2))
```

```json
[
  {
    "kty": "RSA",
    "use": "sig",
    "kid": "nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEg",
    "x5t": "nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEg",
    "n": "oaLLT",
    "e": "AQAB",
    "x5c": [
      "44Dw7"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

try that out:

```
import json


def check_dicts(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, 'r+') as _f1, open(file2, 'r+') as _f2:
        _f1 = json.load(_f1)
        _f2 = json.load(_f2)
    return [d for d in _f1.get('keys') if d in _f2.get('keys')]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(json.dumps(check_dicts(file1='file1.txt', file2='file2'), indent=4))
```

seems like I'm a bit late)

Comment: this works well too. thanks for this option.

Comment: I'm a bit late too, but we both arrived to the same solution (the list comprehension) 

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `json1_dict["keys"]` with `json2_dict["keys"]` wich are, obviously, different.

You should compare the elements inside those lists.

Try this way:

```
json1_dict = getjwk1()
json2_dict = getjwk2()

common_pairs = { "keys": [k for k in json1_dict["keys"] if k in json2_dict["keys"]] }

print(json.dumps(common_pairs, indent = 2))
```

Comment: appreciate the alternative. many ways to deal with this.

Comment: One thing I forgot to add. Could I return this as boolean? In other words since I do have an intersect, how do i return it as true?

Comment: just return [k for k in json1_dict["keys"] if k in json2_dict["keys"]] != []

Comment: SyntaxError: 'return' outside function - does this need to be in a function? couldn't get it to work. thx